# HSSF Reading Blank Cell getting Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, hssf

I am working on the utility which dumps the excel sheet content to the database (postgres 9.2 in my case) , The application is working very smoothly when all the cells are filled but whenever i am trying to run my code on the excel sheet which is having empty cell it is giving me NULL POINTER EXCEPTION . Can any one help me......?

code.... snips ...

```
public ArrayList fillList(int colIndex, int id, List<Cell> cells,
        String path) {
    // OrderedMap errorMap=new LinkedMap();
    String error = null;
    ArrayList<String> errorList = new ArrayList<String>();
    // errorList=null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream(path);

        POIFSFileSystem fs;

        fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fileIn);

        HSSFWorkbook filename = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);
        Cell number = null;
        HSSFSheet sheet = filename.getSheetAt(0);
        Row firstRow = sheet.getRow(0);
        int flag = 0;

        String errorValue = null;

        int columnNo = colIndex;
        if (columnNo != -1) {
            for (Row row : sheet) {
                if (row.getRowNum() != 0) {
                    Cell c = row.getCell(columnNo);
                   // row.getCell(arg0, arg1)
                    // cells.add(c);
                    System.out.println(c.getCellType());
                    if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING && 
                             (id == 2 || id == 3)) {
                        cells.add(c);
                    } else if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC
                            && id == 1) {
                        String s = row.getCell(columnNo).toString();
                        double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
                        String mob = Double.toString(d);
                        Cell sc = row.createCell((short) 2);
                        String text = NumberToTextConverter.toText(c
                                .getNumericCellValue());
                        // System.out.println(text);
                        sc.setCellValue(text);
                        cells.add(sc);
                        // Date date=c.getDateCellValue();

                    } else if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC && id == 4) {
                        String s = row.getCell(columnNo).toString();
                        double d = HSSFDateUtil.getExcelDate(c
                                .getDateCellValue());
                        // String date = Double.toString(d);
                        Cell sc = row.createCell((short) 2);
                        String date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy")
                                .format(c.getDateCellValue());
                        // System.out.println(text);
                        sc.setCellValue(date);
                        cells.add(sc);

                    } 
                    else if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK && id == 1   ) {
                        String s = row.getCell(columnNo).toString();
                        Cell sc = row.createCell((short)2);
                        sc.setCellValue("-");
                        cells.add(sc);

                    }
                    else {
                        switch (c.getCellType()) {
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                            errorValue = Double.toString(c
                                    .getNumericCellValue());
                            break;
                        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                            errorValue = c.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        }

                        errorList.add(c.getRowIndex() + "$" + columnNo
                                + "$" + errorValue + "$" + id);
                    }
                    /*
                     * if (c == null || c.getCellType() ==
                     * Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) { cells.add(c); } else {
                     * 
                     * cells.add(c);
                     * 
                     * }
                     */

                    flag = 1;
                }// if to skip 1st row
            }
        } else {
            // System.out.println("could not find column " + columnWanted +
            // " in first row of " + fileIn.toString());
        }
        return errorList;
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
    }
    return errorList;
}
```

Comment: What line is the exception on?

Comment: so test the cell to see if it is null first.

Comment: @David Wallance   System.out.println(c.getCellType());  whenever the loop is running on empty cell it thows null pointer exception at this line

Comment: @user2310289 , I have tried with that condition also but it is not entering in null condition

Comment: How did you test for null?

Comment: So how are you populating the `sheet` variable?  It looks like you are putting nulls in there.  If that's not what you want, then don't do it.  If it IS what you want, then do the null check when you take values out.

Comment: if (c == null) this condition is working bro...  thanks for ur response ..... merry Chrismas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing how you test for null on the cell, then if it throws a NPE on a certain line you should be about to test for null.

```
  if (c == null)
```

If this really doesn't work then of course you can always catch the NPE

```
  try {
      cellType = c.getCellType();
  } catch (NullPointerException e) {
       // oops Null
       // do something else.
  }
```

Comment: if (c.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK && id == 1   ) {
                        String s = row.getCell(columnNo).toString();
                        Cell sc = row.createCell((short)2);
                        sc.setCellValue("-");
                        cells.add(sc);

                    }                                                       // in this why im checking whether the cell is empty

Comment: so see my first code `if c == null)`  Also if the cell is blank then `row.getCell(columnNo).toString();` looks pretty dangerous too.

Comment: thank you very much.... this code is working as per my requirement ... Thanks once again & merry Christmas ....... !!!!!!!